# Android: onItemClick listener of ListView - how to identify the items?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom `ArrayAdapter` that fills a `ListView`. The data in the adapter is a list of POJOs which I get from a server. Each POJO has a unique id given by the server, I have no influence on that id. The id is only for internal use, means it isn't displayed to the user on the `ListView`.

My intention: if the user clicks an item in the list, I want to pass the id back to the server. The first step would be to create an `onItemClickListener`:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // call the server in a new thread

    // BUT: how do I get the POJO id from this position?

    }
});
```

My problem is: I don't know how to obtain the id of the POJO. Since it is not displayed to the user, is is not in the TextView I get passed in the listener. The other parameters - position and id - do **not** seem to be what I need also. Description:

- position: The position of the view in the adapter.
- id: The row id of the item that was clicked.

I hope you got what I mean, otherwise tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend on how your *adapter* work. The `id` parameter will have a correspondence to one of the items the *adapter* is *adapting*. Based on that `id`, and how your *adapter* works, you can retrieve the original logical item that was represented by the view that was clicked.

Answer (score 4):

the `parent.getItemIdAtPosition(int position)` will give you for pojo object at that index.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Object item = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
}
```

Comment: this returned null for me. I use Pulltorefresh listview

Comment: This means that your adapter's `getItem(int)` method returns null for given position.